# How do I use jq to append an array to this json string?

Tags: bash, jq

I want to append this array to this json string using jq. My result only adds the hello element

```
method=1234
arraynew=(hello world)
echo $arraynew
PAYLOAD=$( jq -Rn \
                  --arg method $method \
                  --arg array $arraynew \
                  '{method: [$method], values: $array}' )
```

I get this return:

```
{ "method": [ "1234" ], "values": "hello" }
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and apply your feed-back to the answers you got.

Comment: Anthony, You still have not accepted and rated the answers you'v got from any of your 5 questions since August, 4. Once again, please take time to review those, and accept one if it helped you. Stack-overflow is a community social network where ppl helps each-other.  Your feed-back on answers is as important as the answers from volunteers  [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Please take time to give your feed-back to all answers you got. It is valuable and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
jq '.[].method += [$method]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to an array like `$arraynew` is equivalent to `${arraynew[0]}` -- you only get the first element.

`jq` expects the `--arg` values to be strings, so we need to join the array into a single string, and then split it within jq:

```sh
jq -n \
   --arg method "$method" \
   --arg array  "$(printf '%s\n' "${arraynew[@]}")" \
    '
        {
            method: [$method],
            values: ($array | split("\n"))
        }    
    '
```

```
{
  "method": [
    "1234"
  ],
  "values": [
    "hello",
    "world"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to use both `-R` and `-n`

Comment: -R is often used with -n when `input` or `inputs` is used.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert your bash array into a json array using `jq`

```sh
printf '%s\0' "${arraynew[@]}" | jq -Rns 'input | split("\u0000")'
```

```json
[
  "hello",
  "world"
]
```

Then, import it to your main `jq` script using `--argjson` instead of `--arg`

```sh
jsonarray="$(
  printf '%s\0' "${arraynew[@]}" | jq -Rns 'input | split("\u0000")'
)"

jq -Rn \
  --arg method "$method" \
  --argjson array "$jsonarray" \
  '{method: [$method], values: $array}'
```

```json
{
  "method": [
    "1234"
  ],
  "values": [
    "hello",
    "world"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass your array elements as positional arguments:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

method=1234
arraynew=(hello world)
declare -p arraynew
payload=$(
  jq -n '{method: $method, values: $ARGS.positional}' \
    --arg method "$method" \
    --args "${arraynew[@]}"
)
printf '%s\n' "$payload"
```

But it has the limitation of system's maximum argument line length, so will work only with shorter arrays of small elements.

Or you can pass your array as a `null`-delimited elements stream, and have `jq` read it into a string to be split on `null` delimiters into a JSON array like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

method=1234
arraynew=(hello world)
declare -p arraynew

payload=$(
  printf '%s\0' "${arraynew[@]}" |
  jq -Rs '{method: $method, values: split("\u0000")}' \
    --arg method "$method"
)
printf '%s\n' "$payload"
```